# Regular Expression for Separating Paths

Tags: java, regex

Hello I was trying to use Java regular expression to get the required context path from the following path information.

```
String path = "/Systems/lenovo/";
```

I want to write regular expression to get "/Systems" and "/lenovo" separately.

I tried the following regular expression using groups but not working as expected.

```
String systemString = path.replaceAll("(.*)(/\\w+)([/][\\w+])", "$2") - to get "/Systems" - not working

String lenovoString = path.replaceAll("(.*)(/\\w+)([/][\\w+])", "$3") - to get "/lenovo" - working.
```

Could any body tell me what might be the wrong in my Regx?

Comment: For this kind of manipulations, `Pattern` is a way saner choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use this `replaceAll` with `groups ($3)` approach to get what you want.

What happens behind the scene with your approach is:

regex `(.*)(/\\w+)([/][\\w+])` matches the string `/Systems/l`

Your expression is divided into the following groups:

```
$1 => (.*)
$2 => (/\\w+)
$3 => ([/][\\w+])
```

Each group matched the following part of your matched string `/Systems/l`

```
$1 => ''
$2 => /Systems
$3 => /l
```

So when you do

`path.replaceAll("(.*)(/\\w+)([/][\\w+])", "$3")`

you are essentially doing

```
'/Systems/lenovo/'.replaceAll(`/Systems/l`, '/l') => '/lenovo'
```

And when you use `$2`

```
'/Systems/lenovo/'.replaceAll(`/Systems/l`, '/Systems') => '/Systemsenovo/'
```

So it doesn't really make sense to use regex groups for this task and better use simple `String.split` method as others suggested on this page

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
String PATH_SEPARATOR = "/"; 
String str = "/Systems/lenovo/";
String[] res = str.substring(1).split(PATH_SEPARATOR);
```

[IDEONE DEMO](https://ideone.com/4koJ63)

And if you want to retain the `/` before the string then you can simply add it like:

```
"/"+res[0]
```

[IDEONE DEMO](https://ideone.com/4koJ63)

Answer (score 2):

Just split like this:

```
String[] parts = path.replaceAll("/$", "").split("(?=/)");
```

The `replaceAll()` call is to remove the trailing slash (if any).

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/ysCAXT) of

```
String path = "/Systems/lenovo/";
String[] parts = path.replaceAll("/$", "").split("(?=/)");
Arrays.stream(parts).forEach(System.out::println);
```

producing

```
/Systems
/lenovo
```

Comment: Clever way to retain the `/` !

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
String path = "/Systems/lenovo/";
String[] arr = path.split("/");
String str1 = "/"+arr[1];
String str2 = "/"+arr[2];
System.out.println("str1 = " + str1);
System.out.println("str2 = " + str2);
```

And the result:

```
str1 = /Systems
str2 = /lenovo
```

Answer (score 0):

To get /Systems, you need this regex: (?:\/[^\/]+)
and for /lenovo, you need: (?:\/[^\/]+){1}(?=\/$)

You can try this (see http://ideone.com/dB3edh):

```
   String path = "/Systems/lenovo/";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:\\/[^\\/]+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(path);

    if(m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(0));
    }
    p = Pattern.compile("(?:\\/[^\\/]+){1}(?=\\/$)");
    m = p.matcher(path);
    if(m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(0));
    }
```